# Python: object has no attribute

Tags: python

I have two classes: MyClass and MyClass2. For MyClass I took a file and returned every word on that file. In MyClass2 I inherited MyClass and basically wrote a code that was supposed to store all the words in a dictionary along with a frequency of the words as the values.
The first class I already tested and it was able to return every word. MyClass2 I thought I had written correctly, but I think I'm not inheriting MyClass right or my **iter** method is written incorreclty. Every time I try to run my code, it returns an error.
**Since this is a homework assignment, (Also I don't want to be thought of as cheating..) I won't post all my code unless it is necessary to answer my questions nor will I be expecting anyone to rewrite or completely fix my code.** I just need some guidance on whether or not my constructor is wrong or if the entire code is wrong, or if I'm just not formatting my code correctly and inheriting the class wrong...? 
I am new to python and I just need help.

```
from myclass import MyClass
class MyClass2(MyClass):
      def __init__(self, Dict):    #Is the problem within the constructor?
          self.Dict = Dict
          Dict = {}
      def dict(self, textfile):
          text = MyClass(textfile)    #Was I wrong here??
          ..................
              ..............
              ..............
              return self.Dict
      def __iter__(self):
          for key, value in self.Dict.items():
              yield key, value
```

When I run a test code, I get an error that says :

```
AttributeError: 'MyClass2' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Please let me know if I am missing anythign or if there isn't enough information.

I tested it using this code which was given:

```
filename = MyClass1('name of file')
y = MyClass2(filename)
for x in y:
    print x
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\myclass.py", line 25, in <module>
  for x in y:
File "C:\myclass2.py", line 19, in __iter__
  for key, value in self.Dict.items():
AttributeError: 'MyClass2' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: Does `MyClass` has the attribute `items`?

Comment: what tpe is Dict that's passed into the constructor?  Also Dict = {} is most likely not doing what you're thinking it does.  What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Where else are you using "items" in your code?

Comment: How do you instantiate `MyClass2`?

Comment: Also, since we can't see the full code, Can you provide the full traceback instead?

Comment: For MyCLass I test using file = MyClass('name of fiel') for x in file: print x and then for MyClass2 I do: y = MyClass2(file) for x in y: print x

Comment: I think also items() does not mean what I think it means? I thought it allowed you to access keys and values ina dictionary so that I coudl use for key, value in dict.items(): print key, value .

Comment: For dict= {}, does this mean my constructor is incorrect and I'm not creating a dictionary the right way?

Comment: Do not use 'reserver' words (such as 'dict', even capitalized) although it is allowed: your code will be less error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables' naming is quite weird. I'll try to unwind it:

```
from myclass import MyClass
class MyClass2(MyClass):
      def __init__(self, Dict):
          self.Dict = Dict
          Dict = {}
      def __iter__(self):
          for key, value in self.Dict.items():
              yield key, value

filename = MyClass1('name of file')
y = MyClass2(filename)
```

Here, `filename` is not a file name (which I would suspect of being a `str` or `unicode`). Maybe it is an object somehow containing the file name. (The naming `MyClass1` is not very helpful.)

This object, referred to by `filename` is given to `MyClass2.__init__()`. There it gets put into `self.Dict`. And then, the parameter `Dict` is set to `{}`, which is quite pointless.

Alas, I don't know what you want to achieve. Maybe you want something like

```
class MyClass2(MyClass):
      def __init__(self, filename):
          self.filename = filename
          self.Dict = {}
      def __iter__(self):
          for key, value in self.Dict.items():
              yield key, value
```

Note: It would be better to name variables in lowercase. And don't rename `Dict` just do `dict`, but name it in a way that a reader can see what it is supposed to mean.

Comment: Thank you. That actually did get rid of my error. After running my test code it didn't print anything except for the output from MyClass. MyClass2 was supposed to print the key and value of the dictionary after running the test code. Does this mean that def __iter__(self) in MyClass2 is wrong or is it somewhere else in this class?

Comment: @user2918801 No, it was your `__init__` which did things in the wrong order and some even pointless. Assigning to a local variable is pointless here; in order to preserve things, you mus assign to an attribute of `self` such as `self.filename` or `self.datadict`.